# Setting up network from a "minimal" CentOS 6.4 install

Tags: networking, centos

Just installed CentOS 6.4 from a "minimal" ISO.

On first boot, I discover that I cannot ping the outside world, `yum update`, or anything like that: `connect: Network is unreachable`.  In fact, I can't even ping the router.

This is on a wired ethernet connection that works fine with no configuration on the same box in Haiku and even BeOS (and at one point, PC-BSD.)

Is my somewhat ancient onboard ethernet not supported by CentOS, or do I need to do something special here?  I noticed on another CentOS 6.4 minimal install on a different box and network that if I didn't specify network settings manually during the GUI installer, I was stuck in a similar situation afterwards, but IIRC I could at least get to the router.

Comment: The answers there actually wouldn't have helped me: the minimal ISO does not install a GUI, and the answer with ONBOOT did not have NM_CONTROLLED.  I'm not sure if NM_CONTROLLED makes a difference, but our contexts are different too: I had more than just the loopback, and this is on bare metal, not in a VM.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It was [as intuitive as](http://www.convirture.com/ee_wiki/index.php?title=RedHat_6_Networking) using `vi` to edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, toggling the two lines

```
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="no"
```

to their opposites, and then

```
/etc/init.d/network restart
```

Everything works.